# Using ruby's OptionParser to parse sub-commands

Tags: ruby, optparse, optionparser

I'd like to be able to use ruby's OptionParser to parse sub-commands of the form

```
COMMAND [GLOBAL FLAGS] [SUB-COMMAND [SUB-COMMAND FLAGS]]
```

like:

```
git branch -a
gem list foo
```

I know I could switch to a different option parser library (like Trollop), but I'm interested in learning how to do this from within OptionParser, since I'd like to learn the library better.

Any tips?

Comment: No tips, aside from a suggestion to remain open to switching directions. In my experience, `OptionParser` has been frustrating to use for several reasons, one of them being the poor documentation -- hence your question. William Morgan, the author of Trollop, shows no mercy in his criticism (for example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897630/really-cheap-command-line-option-parsing-in-ruby and http://trollop.rubyforge.org). I can't dispute what he says.

Comment: @FM: Well, like the author of that question, I'm stuck on a machine where importing libraries is a PITA, so I'm trying to make do with the standard libs - like `optparse`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Figured it out.  I need to use `OptionParser#order!`.  It will parse all the options from the start of `ARGV` until it finds a non-option (that isn't an option argument), removing everything it processes from `ARGV`, and then it will quit.

So I just need to do something like:

```
global = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  # ...
end
subcommands = { 
  'foo' => OptionParser.new do |opts|
     # ...
   end,
   # ...
   'baz' => OptionParser.new do |opts|
     # ...
   end
 }

 global.order!
 subcommands[ARGV.shift].order!
```

Comment: For reference, a more complete example is in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/rkumar/445735).

Comment: What if `foo` and `baz` share a lot of common options? How to avoid repetition?

Comment: Fernando Á : simple, just abstract the common options out to a method.  `def common_options(&blk) ; OptionParser.new { |opts| opts.on(...) ; ... ; blk.call(opts) } ; end`, then call that method with a block for subcommand-specific options later - `subcommands = { 'foo' => common_options { |opts| ... }, 'baz' => common_options { |opts| ... }, ... }`

Comment: Could you provide an example in code for this please?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the OptionParser syntax has changed some.  I had to use the following so that the arguments array had all of the options not parsed by the opts object.

```
begin
  opts.order!(arguments)
rescue OptionParser::InvalidOption => io
  # Prepend the invalid option onto the arguments array
  arguments = io.recover(arguments)
rescue => e
  raise "Argument parsing failed: #{e.to_s()}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

GLI is the way to go, https://github.com/davetron5000/gli.  An excerpt from a tutorial:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'gli'
require 'hacer'

include GLI::App

program_desc 'A simple todo list'

flag [:t,:tasklist], :default_value => File.join(ENV['HOME'],'.todolist')

pre do |global_options,command,options,args|
  $todo_list = Hacer::Todolist.new(global_options[:tasklist])
end

command :add do |c|
  c.action do |global_options,options,args|
    $todo_list.create(args)
  end
end

command :list do |c|
  c.action do
    $todo_list.list.each do |todo|
      printf("%5d - %s\n",todo.todo_id,todo.text)
    end
  end
end

command :done do |c|
  c.action do |global_options,options,args|
    id = args.shift.to_i
    $todo_list.list.each do |todo|
      $todo_list.complete(todo) if todo.todo_id == id
    end
  end
end

exit run(ARGV)
```

You can find the tutorial at http://davetron5000.github.io/gli/.

Answer (score 0):

There are also other gems you can look at such as [main](http://codeforpeople.com/lib/ruby/main/).

Comment: @rampion: You can look at the samples, for example http://codeforpeople.com/lib/ruby/main/main-2.8.3/samples/f.rb