# Option parsing standard

Tags: ruby, unix, scripting, command-line, arguments

I've seen a number of option parsing libraries out there for ruby, but they all come with weird constraints about them.

'executable' gem claims that all command line binaries must have a syntax "binary

'micro-optparse' can't handle trailing list of filenames and requires you have defaults for all non-boolean commands. Strange.

Some other one I used made it impossible to run a command without arguments.

And so on and so on. And I don't want to parse ARGV myself.

Is there anything close to a specification or standard for command line options and arguments? And then what option parsing library complies to that standard?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897630/really-cheap-command-line-option-parsing-in-ruby ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about [optparse](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/index.html)? It's included in stdlib - as standard as it gets.

But there is no unix standard set in stone as to parsing command-line parameters.

You should define your requirements more clearly and then choose a library that suits them.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard I have ever heard of, but AFAIR [Trollop](http://trollop.rubyforge.org/) was started out of the frustration with the other command line parsers.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Michael Kohl's mention of Trollop.  Trollop makes it very easy to write command line options that conform to the gnu style.

I wrote a simple self-contained example in [How do I make a Ruby script using Trollop for command line parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357953/how-do-i-get-started-with-trollop-the-command-line-parser-package).