# How can I do really cheap command line parsing in Python?

Tags: python, ruby, parsing, command-line-arguments

I've been making heavy use of the answer in "[Really Cheap Command-Line Option Parsing in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897630/really-cheap-command-line-option-parsing-in-ruby)". It's great and for my purposes, always what I need.

Now I find myself back in Python land for a bit because of internal library support for something I want to do. I'm considering porting it to Ruby but that's beyond the scope of this question, but I'd like to use something similar.

Here is the really cheap method I use often in Ruby:

```
$quiet       = ARGV.delete('-d')
$interactive = ARGV.delete('-i')
```

If there is a `"-d"` in the `ARGV` array, then `$quiet` is set to `"-d"` and not nil. If there is no `"-d"`, then `$quiet` becomes `nil`.

Is there something similar I could do in Python?

Comment: Have you checked argparse?

Comment: I am familiar with argparse but it's more heavy weight than what I posted above IIRC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to use `sys.argv`:

```
from sys import argv
quiet = '-d' in argv # True if '-d' in argv else False
```

If you want to remove `'-d'` from the `argv`, change the second line to this:

```
quiet = '-d' in argv and (argv.remove('-d') or True)
```

If this reduces its cheapness, let's make a function of it:

```
getArg = lambda x: x in argv and (argv.remove(x) or True)
quiet = getArg('-d')
interactive = getArg('-i')
```

Comment: Really Cheap, fits requirements

Comment: Absolutely.  Does what's wanted.

Comment: Doesn't remove the option from the args if it's found, which makes using what's left over (as filenames etc.) harder.

Comment: @kindall change the line as this : `quiet = '-d' in argv and (argv.remove('-d') or True)`

Comment: better to write a small one liner function then. :)

Comment: once you're writing the one line function though, i think you've already lost the cheapness. Luckily I don't *need* to remove the arguments from the array - that's just the functionality provided in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Python has a few nice libraries for argument parsing:

1. [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html)
2. [optparse (depreciated since 2.7)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html)

Example:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-d", action='store_true')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import sys

quiet = 1 if "-d" in sys.argv else None
```

Comment: This works accurately but mbcoder's response is a bit more thorough and provides a shorter syntax I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-d", action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

if (args.d):
   Print "D switch is on!"
```

Comment: don't you need to make a new argparser object first? something like `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')` from http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

Comment: Yes.  Like jh314 sez.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the lightest way (if you don't want to use `argparse`) is going to be a helper function:

```
import sys

def flag(arg):
    try:
        index = sys.argv.index(arg)
    except ValueError:
        return None
    else:
        return sys.argv.pop(index)
```

Usage:

```
quiet, interactive = flag("-d"), flag("-i")
```

Of course, since these are just flags, you could return `True` and `False` instead of `None` and the arg, but I've tried to keep it as similar to the Ruby functionality as posisble.