# Parse command line arguments in a Ruby script

Tags: ruby, command-line

I want to call a Ruby script from the command line, and pass in parameters that are key/value pairs.

Command line call:

```
$ ruby my_script.rb --first_name=donald --last_name=knuth
```

my_script.rb:

```
puts args.first_name + args.last_name
```

What is the standard Ruby way to do this? In other languages I usually have to use an option parser. In Ruby I saw we have `ARGF.read`, but that does not seem to work key/value pairs like in this example.

[OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#method-i-getopts) looks promising, but I can't tell if it actually supports this case.

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/CLI_Option_Parsers

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Highline seems like helper functions to ask users for input. So I would use Highline to have my console say `First Name: ` and await their input. Is there a particular function I should be looking at in it?

Comment: There are many gems you can choose from; that website categorizes the libraries and sorts them by popularity. I even wrote my own gem, called `acclaim`, and it does support the `--option=value` syntax. I haven't had the time to maintain my free software projects, though. You should pick a better-supported library.

Comment: Here's a good tutorial on the options parser: http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/ruby-scripting-tutorial/optionparser-tutorial.php

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Based on the answer by @MartinCortez here's a short one-off that makes a hash of key/value pairs, where the values must be joined with an `=` sign. It also supports flag arguments without values:

```
args = Hash[ ARGV.join(' ').scan(/--?([^=\s]+)(?:=(\S+))?/) ]
```

…or alternatively…

```
args = Hash[ ARGV.flat_map{|s| s.scan(/--?([^=\s]+)(?:=(\S+))?/) } ]
```

Called with `-x=foo -h --jim=jam` it returns `{"x"=>"foo", "h"=>nil, "jim"=>"jam"}` so you can do things like:

```
puts args['jim'] if args.key?('h')
#=> jam
```

---

While there are multiple libraries to handle this—including [`GetoptLong` included with Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/getoptlong/rdoc/GetoptLong.html)—I personally prefer to roll my own. Here's the pattern I use, which makes it reasonably generic, not tied to a specific usage format, and flexible enough to allow intermixed flags, options, and required arguments in various orders:

```
USAGE = <<ENDUSAGE
Usage:
   docubot [-h] [-v] [create [-s shell] [-f]] directory [-w writer] [-o output_file] [-n] [-l log_file]
ENDUSAGE

HELP = <<ENDHELP
   -h, --help       Show this help.
   -v, --version    Show the version number (#{DocuBot::VERSION}).
   create           Create a starter directory filled with example files;
                    also copies the template for easy modification, if desired.
   -s, --shell      The shell to copy from.
                    Available shells: #{DocuBot::SHELLS.join(', ')}
   -f, --force      Force create over an existing directory,
                    deleting any existing files.
   -w, --writer     The output type to create [Defaults to 'chm']
                    Available writers: #{DocuBot::Writer::INSTALLED_WRITERS.join(', ')}
   -o, --output     The file or folder (depending on the writer) to create.
                    [Default value depends on the writer chosen.]
   -n, --nopreview  Disable automatic preview of .chm.
   -l, --logfile    Specify the filename to log to.

ENDHELP

ARGS = { :shell=>'default', :writer=>'chm' } # Setting default values
UNFLAGGED_ARGS = [ :directory ]              # Bare arguments (no flag)
next_arg = UNFLAGGED_ARGS.first
ARGV.each do |arg|
  case arg
    when '-h','--help'      then ARGS[:help]      = true
    when 'create'           then ARGS[:create]    = true
    when '-f','--force'     then ARGS[:force]     = true
    when '-n','--nopreview' then ARGS[:nopreview] = true
    when '-v','--version'   then ARGS[:version]   = true
    when '-s','--shell'     then next_arg = :shell
    when '-w','--writer'    then next_arg = :writer
    when '-o','--output'    then next_arg = :output
    when '-l','--logfile'   then next_arg = :logfile
    else
      if next_arg
        ARGS[next_arg] = arg
        UNFLAGGED_ARGS.delete( next_arg )
      end
      next_arg = UNFLAGGED_ARGS.first
  end
end

puts "DocuBot v#{DocuBot::VERSION}" if ARGS[:version]

if ARGS[:help] or !ARGS[:directory]
  puts USAGE unless ARGS[:version]
  puts HELP if ARGS[:help]
  exit
end

if ARGS[:logfile]
  $stdout.reopen( ARGS[:logfile], "w" )
  $stdout.sync = true
  $stderr.reopen( $stdout )
end

# etc.
```

Comment: This is nice, but if you're also using the built-in `ARGF` to read streams via filenames/stdin you need to make sure to consume the arguments from `ARGV` before using `ARGF.read` or you will end up with "No such file or directory" errors.

Answer (score 139):

Ruby's built-in [OptionParser](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) does this nicely. Combine it with [OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) and you're home free:

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.on('--first_name FIRSTNAME') { |o| options[:first_name] = o }
  opt.on('--last_name LASTNAME') { |o| options[:last_name] = o }
end.parse!

puts options
```

`options` will contain the parameters and values as a hash.

Saving and running that at the command line with no parameters results in:

```
$ ruby test.rb
{}
```

Running it with parameters:

```
$ ruby test.rb --first_name=foo --last_name=bar
{:first_name=>"foo", :last_name=>"bar"}
```

That example is using a Hash to contain the options, but you can use an OpenStruct which will result in usage like your request:

```
require 'optparse'
require 'ostruct'

options = OpenStruct.new
OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.on('-f', '--first_name FIRSTNAME', 'The first name') { |o| options.first_name = o }
  opt.on('-l', '--last_name LASTNAME', 'The last name') { |o| options.last_name = o }
end.parse!

puts options.first_name + ' ' + options.last_name

$ ruby test.rb --first_name=foo --last_name=bar
foo bar
```

It even automatically creates your `-h` or `--help` option:

```
$ ruby test.rb -h
Usage: test [options]
        --first_name FIRSTNAME
        --last_name LASTNAME
```

You can use short flags too:

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.on('-f', '--first_name FIRSTNAME') { |o| options[:first_name] = o }
  opt.on('-l', '--last_name LASTNAME') { |o| options[:last_name] = o }
end.parse!

puts options
```

Running that through its paces:

```
$ ruby test.rb -h
Usage: test [options]
    -f, --first_name FIRSTNAME
    -l, --last_name LASTNAME
$ ruby test.rb -f foo --l bar
{:first_name=>"foo", :last_name=>"bar"}
```

It's easy to add inline explanations for the options too:

```
OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.on('-f', '--first_name FIRSTNAME', 'The first name') { |o| options[:first_name] = o }
  opt.on('-l', '--last_name LASTNAME', 'The last name') { |o| options[:last_name] = o }
end.parse!
```

and:

```
$ ruby test.rb -h
Usage: test [options]
    -f, --first_name FIRSTNAME       The first name
    -l, --last_name LASTNAME         The last name
```

OptionParser also supports converting the parameter to a type, such as an Integer or an Array. Refer to the documentation for more examples and information.

You should also look at the related questions list to the right:

- "[Really Cheap Command-Line Option Parsing in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897630/really-cheap-command-line-option-parsing-in-ruby?rq=1)"
- "[Pass variables to Ruby script via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244611/pass-variables-to-ruby-script-via-command-line?rq=1)"

Comment: How is this not the top answer?

Comment: I dunno. As they say, "Different strokes for different folks."

Answer (score 10):

There is a number of command line arguments parsers in Ruby:

- [`GetoptLong`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/getoptlong/rdoc/GetoptLong.html) - Included in `stdlib`
- [`OptionParser`](https://github.com/ruby/optparse) - No longer part of `stdlib`, [since Ruby 3.0.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2020/12/25/ruby-3-0-0-released/) converted to a separate `optparse` gem
- [`slop`](https://github.com/leejarvis/slop)
- [`optimist`](https://github.com/ManageIQ/optimist)
- [and many more...](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/CLI_Option_Parsers)

Personally I'd choose `slop` or `optimist`, those are not part of standard Ruby installation.

```
gem install slop
```

But it offers simplicity and code readability. Assuming slightly more complex example with required arguments and default values:

```
require 'slop'

begin
  opts = Slop.parse do |o|
    o.int '-a', '--age', 'Current age', default: 42
    o.string '-f', '--first_name', 'The first name', required: true
    o.string '-l', '--last_name', 'The last name', required: true
    o.bool '-v', '--verbose', 'verbose output', default: false
    o.on '-h','--help', 'print the help' do
      puts o
      exit
    end
  end

  p opts.to_hash
rescue Slop::Error => e
  puts e.message
end
```

`optimist` formerly known as `trollop`, it's very easy to ready, with minimum boilerplate code:

```
gem install optimist
```

```
require 'optimist'

opts = Optimist::options do
  opt :verbose, "verbose mode"
  opt :first_name, "The first name", type: :string, required: true
  opt :last_name, "The last name", type: :string, required: true
  opt :age, "Current age", default: 42
end

p opts
```

Similar example using `OptionParser`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'optparse'
require 'ostruct'

begin
  options = OpenStruct.new
  OptionParser.new do |opt|
    opt.on('-a', '--age AGE', 'Current age') { |o| options.age = o }
    opt.on('-f', '--first_name FIRSTNAME', 'The first name') { |o| options.first_name = o }
    opt.on('-l', '--last_name LASTNAME', 'The last name') { |o| options.last_name = o }
    opt.on('-v', '--verbose', 'Verbose output') { |o| options.verbose = true }
  end.parse!

  options[:age] = 42 if options[:age].nil?
  raise OptionParser::MissingArgument.new('--first_name') if options[:first_name].nil?
  raise OptionParser::MissingArgument.new('--last_name') if options[:last_name].nil?
  options[:verbose] = false if options[:verbose].nil?

rescue OptionParser::ParseError => e
  puts e.message
  exit
end
```

`GetoptLong` parsing is even more complicated:

```
require 'getoptlong'

opts = GetoptLong.new(
  [ '--help', '-h', GetoptLong::NO_ARGUMENT ],
  [ '--first_name', '-f', GetoptLong::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT ],
  [ '--last_name', '-l', GetoptLong::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT ],
  [ '--age','-a', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ],
  [ '--verbose','-v', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ]
)
begin
  options = {}
  options[:verbose] = false
  options[:age] = 42
  opts.each do |opt, arg|
    case opt
    when '--help'
        puts <<-EOF
  usage: ./getlongopts.rb [options]

      -a, --age         Current age
      -f, --first_name  The first name
      -l, --last_name   The last name
      -v, --verbose     verbose output
      -h, --help        print the help

        EOF
    when '--first_name'
      options[:first_name] = arg
    when '--last_name'
      options[:last_name] = arg
    when '--age'
      options[:age] = arg.to_i
    when '--verbose'
      options[:verbose] = arg
    else
      puts "unknown option `#{opt}`"
      exit 1
    end
  end

  raise GetoptLong::MissingArgument.new('Missing argument --first_name') if options[:first_name].nil?
  raise GetoptLong::MissingArgument.new('Missing argument --last_name') if options[:last_name].nil?

rescue GetoptLong::Error => e
  puts e.message
  exit
end

puts options
```

Command line arguments was never meant to be a rocket science task, spend your time on reading/writing more useful code :)

Comment: This is a great overview of the available choices and how they compare. Deserves more upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

I personally use [Docopt](http://docopt.org/). This is much more clear, maintainable and easy to read.

Have a look at the Ruby implementation's [documentation](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.rb) for examples. The usage is really straightforward.

```
gem install docopt
```

Ruby code:

```
doc = <<DOCOPT
My program who says hello

Usage:
  #{__FILE__} --first_name=<first_name> --last_name=<last_name>
DOCOPT

begin
  args = Docopt::docopt(doc)
rescue Docopt::Exit => e
  puts e.message
  exit
end

print "Hello #{args['--first_name']} #{args['--last_name']}"
```

Then calling:

```
$ ./says_hello.rb --first_name=Homer --last_name=Simpsons
Hello Homer Simpsons
```

And without arguments:

```
$ ./says_hello.rb
Usage:
  says_hello.rb --first_name=<first_name> --last_name=<last_name>
```

Comment: This is **the only** sane answer for using options in Ruby. **The options are generated and parsed from your help message!** Awesome.

Answer (score 4):

A bit of standard Ruby [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Regexp.html#method-i-named_captures) in `myscript.rb`:

```
args = {}

ARGV.each do |arg|
  match = /--(?<key>.*?)=(?<value>.*)/.match(arg)
  args[match[:key]] = match[:value] # e.g. args['first_name'] = 'donald'
end

puts args['first_name'] + ' ' + args['last_name']
```

And on the command line:

```
$ ruby script.rb --first_name=donald --last_name=knuth
```

Produces:

```
$ donald knuth
```

Comment: That's pretty nice! The requirement to use `=` to disambiguate between `-f foo` and `-x -y bar` is a bit of a non-starter for real-world usage for me, but it's a nice quick hack.

Comment: True. I was just following his format above. Based on the question, I'm not sure if he cares about the disambiguation.

Comment: That looked awesome but how would you define `s`? `ARGV.join.to_s`?

Comment: I can't see it anymore (your comment)

Comment: Yes, I deleted my comment, because it was, as you pointed out, wrong. :) It's in my answer, now. Deleting other comments for clean up.

Answer (score 1):

An improved version that handles arguments that are not options, arguments with a parameter, and `-a` as well as `--a`.

```
def parse(args)
  parsed = {}

  args.each do |arg|
    match = /^-?-(?<key>.*?)(=(?<value>.*)|)$/.match(arg)
    if match
      parsed[match[:key].to_sym] = match[:value]
    else
      parsed[:text] = "#{parsed[:text]} #{arg}".strip
    end
  end

  parsed
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight modification to @Phrogz excellent answer: this mod will allow you to pass a string with spaces in it.

```
args= Hash[ ARGV.join(' ').scan(/--?([^=\s]+)(?:="(.*?)"+)?/)]
```

In a command line pass the string like this:

```
ruby my_script.rb '--first="Boo Boo" --last="Bear"'
```

Or from another ruby script like this:

```
system('ruby my_script.rb \'--first="Boo Boo" --last="Bear"\'')
```

Results:

```
{"first"=>"Boo Boo", "last"=>"Bear"}
```