# Why undefined local variable?

Tags: ruby

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26435303/314813) answer have I the below code which gives

```
undefined local variable or method `username' for main:Object (NameError)
```

**Question**

I assume this worked in 2014, so can anyone see why this doesn't work on a modern version of Ruby?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

USAGE = <<ENDUSAGE
Usage:
   rejse_dumper [-h] [-v] [-u username] [-p password] [-a address]
ENDUSAGE

HELP = <<ENDHELP
   -h, --help       Show this help.
   -u, --username   The login username.
   -p, --password   Force create over an existing directory,
   -a, --address    The URL [Defaults to 'https://example.com']

ENDHELP

ARGS = { address: 'https://example.com' } # Setting default values
ARGV.each do |arg|
  case arg
  when '-h','--help'      then ARGS[:help] = true
  when '-u','--username'  then next_arg    = :username
  when '-p','--password'  then next_arg    = :password
  when '-a','--address'   then next_arg    = :address
    else
       if next_arg
         ARGS[next_arg] = arg
       end
  end
end

if ARGS[:help]
  puts USAGE
  puts HELP if ARGS[:help]
  exit
end

puts username
puts password
puts address
```

Comment: You're telling ruby to output the value of `username` via the `puts username`, but `username` isn't defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code puts the command line arguments into a hash in this part:

```
if next_arg
  ARGS[next_arg] = arg
end
```

but doesn't set up individual variables such as `username`, `password` etc. hence the error you're seeing.

so you can refer to the arguments like this:

```
ARGS[:username]
```

or assign them to individual variables:

```
username = ARGS[:username]
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, your assumption is incorrect.

To make it working, change:

```
puts username
puts password
puts address
```

to:

```
puts ARGS[:username]
puts ARGS[:password]
puts ARGS[:address]
```