# Parse multiple command line options in Ruby using OptionParser

Tags: ruby, parsing, command-line, optionparser

I've just started using OptionParser for Ruby and I wanted to use flags that would use more than just one argument.

For instance, I would like to be able to run:

```
script --move src dst
```

Note how `src` and `dst` are not separated using a coma.

My initial idea was:

```
opts.on("-m src dst", "--move src dst ", "move file from SRCto DST") do |src|
    # do something
end
```

But this is not working. I assume that this is not the right approach. But how could this be done?

Comment: There is very good example in documentation http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html  under heading `Generating Help`, which shows how to accept a parameter called `name`.  Same can be extended for your case of `src` and `dst`.  You need to repeat what example shows for `name` - once for `src` and once for `dst` as two separate `opts.on` statements

Comment: OP is specifically asking how to accept two consecutive values for the same option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OptionParser doesn't support that; It could be patched to do so, but I'm not sure it's worth the trouble.

Consider this code:

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.on('-m', '--move') { |o| options[:move] = o }
end.parse!

from_name, to_name = ARGV

puts "Should move: #{ options.key?(:move) }"
puts "From: #{ from_name }"
puts "To: #{ to_name }"
```

Saving it and running it with various combinations of the parameters returns:

```
> ruby test.rb --move from to
Should move: true
From: from
To: to

> ruby test.rb  from to
Should move: false
From:
To:
```

If the code is supposed to move files by default then don't bother with the `--move` flag, simply use:

```
test.rb from to
```

and consider removing the OptionParser block entirely.

If the code is supposed to normally copy with the option to move, then `--move` becomes more sensible to act as a flag that moving is desired.

```
ruby test.rb --move from to
```

I'd have code that tests for `options[:move]` and run the code to move instead of copy at that point.

In either case, the filenames shouldn't be tied to the flag, they should be supplied separately and retrieved from `ARGV` after OptionParser has finished parsing the command-line and removing entries it's handled.

Answer (score 3):

The example under the "Complete Example" section of the [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) details how a list of items can be accepted.

Here is a sample program based on that example. The third parameter `Array` in `opts.on` indicates that input `src, dst` should be used to create an array.  To run this sample, you need to do `gem install trollop`.

```
# test.rb
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.on("-m src, dst", "--move src, dst", Array, "Move from src to dst") do |list|
    options[:src] = list[0]
    options[:dst] = list[1]
  end
end.parse!

puts options # It's a hash of parsed options
```

Sample run:

```
> ruby test.rb -m from,to
{:src=>"src", :dst=>"dst"}

>ruby test.rb -h
Usage: test [options]
    -m, --move src, dst              Move from src to dst
```

The above script forces one to separate the options using comma.

---

As indicated by "[Really Cheap Command-Line Option Parsing in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1012930/794242)", there seems to be a gem, [trollop](https://rubygems.org/gems/trollop), that can be quite easy to use for command-line parsing.

A sample program based on Trollop is given below, which allows usage of spaces for specifying options with multiple values

```
# test.rb

require "trollop"

opts = Trollop::options do
  banner "Command line parsing using Trollop"
  opt :move, "--move src dst', Move from src to dst", :short => "-m", :long => "--move", :type => :strings
end
# An array of option values
p opts.move
```

Sample run:

```
>ruby test.rb -m hello world
["hello", "world"]

>ruby test.rb -h
Command line parsing using Trollop
  -m, --move=<s+>    '--move src dst', Move from src to dst
  -h, --help         Show this message
```

There is a subtle difference between the help output between the two approaches.  Trollop produces help text where `--move=<s+>` does not indicate clearly that it needs accepts two values, so I had to repeat the command syntax description.

Comment: Thank you very much, as of today I am using this format. Do you reckon that there is away to get rid of the comma? So, instead of --move src, dst... you could just write --move src dst... but cheers anyway :)

Comment: I am trying to figure that out, if I discover something I will update the answer.  I think `OptionParser#accept` method will play some role but documentation is bit weak in explaining the parameters of `accept` method